# hibernate createSQLQuery bulk insert

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

i try to execute these 3 statements, 1 and 2 success, but when reach 3 statement, i get error, is it because i trying to insert into same table during statement 2  and cause statement 3 fail? by the way, all 3 statement is inside one @spring transaction

```
session.createSQLQuery(" select groupid from group_ where groupid = 888880005").executeQuery;//executed ok 

session.createSQLQuery(" insert into layoutset (layoutsetid,groupid,companyid,privatelayout,logo,logoid,themeid,colorschemeid, wapthemeid,wapcolorschemeid,pagecount) values (888880005, 888880005, 1,0,0,0,'classic','03','mobile','01',0) ").executeUpdate();//executed ok 

session.createSQLQuery(" insert into layoutset (layoutsetid,groupid,companyid,privatelayout,logo,logoid,themeid,colorschemeid, wapthemeid,wapcolorschemeid,pagecount) values (888890005, 888880005, 1,0,0,0,'classic','03','mobile','01',0) ").executeUpdate(); //this fail with

com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.ORMException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
            at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.ExceptionTranslator.translate(ExceptionTranslator.java:41)
            at com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:70)
            at com.company.service.companyPersistenceImpl.doTest(companyPersistenceImpl.java:53)
            at com.company.service.companyLocalServiceImpl.doTest(companyLocalServic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two inserts are exactly the same (same values for columns `layoutsetid,groupid,companyid,privatelayout`); the failure is due to a key-constraint I guess.
what is the primary key of your table?

Comment: tatement 2 and 3 are different, check the primary key 888880005 and 888890005

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the entire stacktrace? Seems to be some lines missing there.

However besides the different layoutsetid the two last queries are the same, which is pretty pointless. Probably there are some database constraints on the table to prevent this which result in the error.

Comment: statement 2 and 3 are different, check the primary key 888880005 and 888890005